# Javascript /jQuery Stock Chart API with multiple separate axis but combined interaction (pic included)?

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I have looked through a number of open source and proprietary charting tools such as:

- [Stock Chart v3](http://www.amcharts.com/stock-chart/)
- [HIGHSTOCK](http://www.highcharts.com/products/highstock)
- [dygraphs](http://dygraphs.com/tutorial.html)
- [Virtualization](http://demos.kendoui.com/dataviz/financial/virtualization.html)

These are all good charting options, some have an added dataset in a separate panel used with interaction(Only Volume). I would like to have this with multiple charts, like this:

[image: Separate axis]

In the above image, there are separate charts for different indicators but when interacting with the chart you can see the values on the right side of all 5 indicators.

Would it be possible to append another chart and have combined interaction in the same way with any existing charting options?

Comment: Could you explain in more detials, what you mean? I.e you have five charts, and trigger action on first chart, on second one should be also called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `amCharts` you are not limited to 2 panels. You can have any number of them. It's just this example that has two. I guess most of other tools does the same.